# can Java Swing JPanel Hold a String Value?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Can a Java Swing JPanel hold a String value than can be modified/accessed where I can save some information?

I see no other option but to implement my own class holding a JPanel and a String... was just trying to save some space/coding..

I like the setName/getName of the Component super class... is there any inconvenience in using that ??

Comment: I already know that I can create a class of my own that can hold a JPanel plus the string variable that will hold that (whatever) value.. I am just asking if I can do it from within JPanel

Comment: why don't create a class that contain `JPanel` and `String`

Comment: @Braj.. please check my previous comment...

Comment: yes you are going in right direction. Add it in question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it can. Any Swing component can hold `client properties` for the specific component.

See the `putClientProperty(...)` and `getClientProperty(...)` methods of JComponent. Using this approach you can define any number of client properties:

```
panel.putClientProperty("Title", "Panel1");
panel.putClientProperty("Description", "some text for the description");
```

You can also use the `setName(..)` and `getName()` methods if you just want to uniquely identify the panel with a string name. Many IDE's will use this property.

Of course if you are creating a panel with multiple Swing components and related instance variables then you would probably extend JPanel and customize its behaviour.

> I like the setName/getName of the Component super class... is there any inconvenience in using that ??

If you feel the "name" property adequately describies the data you want to store then this is the most efficient way to store the data. However, if the data is not really the name of the component then don't force the data just because it is easy to use. Also it is possible some IDE's may use this property for generic debugging or messaging. That it may check display this value in an error message to help identify a specific component.

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions, and it's hard to know what you're looking for here. You could create a `MyJPanel` class that extends `JPanel` and is identical except including a String field with getter/setter. You could also store information in silly ways like by setting/getting the name of the JPanel. (That is use `setName` and `getName` of the `Component` superclass.) Another solution is to add a JLabel or some other component with that information to the JPanel, and if necessary, making it invisible or hidden.

Comment: I like the setName/getName though... is there any inconvenience in using that ??

Answer (score 1):

No, I think it cannot hold a String value.

You can see all getters/setters here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

Also, you can check the source code (if you want to go that far).

There's no getter/setter useful for holding a String value
(I mean ... e.g. no setText or setTitle).

Of course, you can add e.g. an invisible JTextField to your JPanel and
set the String into the JTextField. But that doesn't seem very nice to me.

Comment: If that's the case, I think I'd better create my own implementation of JPanel....

Comment: `There's no getter/setter useful for holding a String value` - You can use the `client properties` of any Swing component.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Component like JLabel/JTextField and use `setVisible(false)`. That object can hold strings.

note: Only for Buttons.
You could use `setAtionCommand()` but it is indented for something very specific. It would be horrible practice for anything else.

Comment: -1, JPanel does not have a `setActionCommand()` method. That method is for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

JPanels hold JComponents, i.e. JButtons, JLabels, etc. A String is not a component. It would be best if you'd just use a JLabel with a String as its parameter, then add that to a JPanel.